# Complete async OpenSSL example

Tags: c, asynchronous, linux, openssl, ssl

I am trying to create a fully async example of a client and server using SSL.

I think these are the required assumptions:

1. Connecting may require socket readability and writeability notifications.
2. When the socket is readable, `SSL_write` may need to be called depending on the result of the last call to `SSL_write`.
3. When the socket is writable, `SSL_read` may need to be called depending on the result of the last call to `SSL_read`.
4. If the last call to `SSL_connect`, `SSL_write`, or `SLL_read` returned `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`, then the application cannot write anything new with `SSL_write` until the last call is recalled.
5. On the connecting side, `SSL_write` cannot be called until `SSL_connect` succeeds.

Are there any others?

On the accepting side, how can I tell if the socket is ready for a call to `SSL_write`?

Here is an example that seems to work completely. Please tell me if anything is wrong with it.

- It can be compiled with `gcc ssl.c -lssl -lcrypto`.
- The client is run with `./a.out client`.
- The server is run with `./a.out server`.
- You can make a sample pem for use by the server with:

```
echo -e "\n\n\n\n\n\n" | /usr/bin/openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout cert.pem -out cert.pem -config openssl.cnf
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -outform DER -out cert.pem.crt
```

---

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

typedef enum {
  CONTINUE,
  BREAK,
  NEITHER
} ACTION;

ACTION ssl_connect(SSL* ssl, int* wants_tcp_write, int* connecting) {
  printf("calling SSL_connect\n");

  int result = SSL_connect(ssl);
  if (result == 0) {
    long error = ERR_get_error();
    const char* error_str = ERR_error_string(error, NULL);
    printf("could not SSL_connect: %s\n", error_str);
    return BREAK;
  } else if (result < 0) {
    int ssl_error = SSL_get_error(ssl, result);
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE) {
      printf("SSL_connect wants write\n");
      *wants_tcp_write = 1;
      return CONTINUE;
    }

    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ) {
      printf("SSL_connect wants read\n");
      // wants_tcp_read is always 1;
      return CONTINUE;
    }

    long error = ERR_get_error();
    const char* error_string = ERR_error_string(error, NULL);
    printf("could not SSL_connect %s\n", error_string);
    return BREAK;
  } else {
    printf("connected\n");
    *connecting = 0;
    return CONTINUE;
  }

  return NEITHER;
}

ACTION ssl_read(SSL* ssl, int* wants_tcp_write, int* call_ssl_read_instead_of_write) {
  printf("calling SSL_read\n");

  *call_ssl_read_instead_of_write = 0;

  char buffer[1024];
  int num = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  if (num == 0) {
    long error = ERR_get_error();
    const char* error_str = ERR_error_string(error, NULL);
    printf("could not SSL_read (returned 0): %s\n", error_str);
    return BREAK;
  } else if (num < 0) {
    int ssl_error = SSL_get_error(ssl, num);
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE) {
      printf("SSL_read wants write\n");
      *wants_tcp_write = 1;
      *call_ssl_read_instead_of_write = 1;
      return CONTINUE;
    }

    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ) {
      printf("SSL_read wants read\n");
      // wants_tcp_read is always 1;
      return CONTINUE;
    }

    long error = ERR_get_error();
    const char* error_string = ERR_error_string(error, NULL);
    printf("could not SSL_read (returned -1) %s\n", error_string);
    return BREAK;
  } else {
    printf("read %d bytes\n", num);
  }

  return NEITHER;
}

ACTION ssl_write(SSL* ssl, int* wants_tcp_write, int* call_ssl_write_instead_of_read,
    int is_client, int should_start_a_new_write) {
  printf("calling SSL_write\n");

  static char buffer[1024];
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  static int to_write = 0;
  if (!*call_ssl_write_instead_of_read && !to_write && is_client && should_start_a_new_write) {
    to_write = 1024;
    printf("decided to write %d bytes\n", to_write);
  }

  if (*call_ssl_write_instead_of_read && (!to_write || !buffer)) {
    printf("ssl should not have requested a write from a read if no data was waiting to be written\n");
    return BREAK;
  }

  *call_ssl_write_instead_of_read = 0;

  if (!to_write) {
    return NEITHER;
  }

  int num = SSL_write(ssl, buffer, to_write);
  if (num == 0) {
    long error = ERR_get_error();
    const char* error_str = ERR_error_string(error, NULL);
    printf("could not SSL_write (returned 0): %s\n", error_str);
    return BREAK;
  } else if (num < 0) {
    int ssl_error = SSL_get_error(ssl, num);
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE) {
      printf("SSL_write wants write\n");
      *wants_tcp_write = 1;
      return CONTINUE;
    }

    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ) {
      printf("SSL_write wants read\n");
      *call_ssl_write_instead_of_read = 1;
      // wants_tcp_read is always 1;
      return CONTINUE;
    }

    long error = ERR_get_error();
    const char* error_string = ERR_error_string(error, NULL);
    printf("could not SSL_write (returned -1): %s\n", error_string);
    return BREAK;
  } else {
    printf("wrote %d of %d bytes\n", num, to_write);
    if (to_write < num) {
      *wants_tcp_write = 1;
    } else {
      *wants_tcp_write = 0;
    }
    to_write -= num;
  }

  return NEITHER;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc != 2 || (strcmp(argv[1], "client") && strcmp(argv[1], "server"))) {
    printf("need parameter 'client' or 'server'\n");
    return 1;
  }

  int is_client = !strcmp(argv[1], "client");
  int port = 10000;

  SSL_library_init();
  SSL_load_error_strings();

  SSL_CTX* ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(is_client ?
      SSLv23_client_method() :
      SSLv23_server_method());
  if (!ssl_ctx) {
    printf("could not SSL_CTX_new\n");
    return 1;
  }

  int sockfd = 0;
  if (is_client) {
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
      printf("could not create socket\n");
      return 1;
    }
  } else {
    const char* certificate = "./cert.pem";
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ssl_ctx, certificate, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) != 1) {
      printf("could not SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file\n");
      return 1;
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ssl_ctx, certificate, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) != 1) {
      printf("could not SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file\n");
      return 1;
    }

    int server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server < 0) {
      printf("could not create socket\n");
      return 1;
    }

    int on = 1;
    if (setsockopt(server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on))) {
      close(server);
      printf("could not setsockopt\n");
      return 1;
    }

    // Bind on any interface.
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(server, (struct sockaddr*)(&addr),
      sizeof(addr))) {
      printf("could not bind\n");
      close(server);
      return 1;
    }

    if (listen(server, 1)) {
      printf("could not listen\n");
      close(server);
      return 1;
    }

    sockfd = accept(server, NULL, NULL);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
      printf("could not create accept\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);
  if (!ssl) {
    printf("could not SSL_new\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Set the socket to be non blocking.
  int flags = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);
  if (fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK)) {
    printf("could not fcntl\n");
    close(sockfd);
    return 1;
  }

  int one = 1;
  if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &one, sizeof(one))) {
    printf("could not setsockopt\n");
    close(sockfd);
    return 1;
  }

  if (is_client) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl((in_addr_t)(0x7f000001));

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)(&addr), sizeof(addr)) && errno != EINPROGRESS) {
      printf("could not connect\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  if (!SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd)) {
    close(sockfd);
    printf("could not SSL_set_fd\n");
    return 1;
  }

  int connecting = 1;
  if (is_client) {
    SSL_set_connect_state(ssl);
  } else {
    SSL_set_accept_state(ssl);
    connecting = 0;
  }

  fd_set read_fds, write_fds;
  int wants_tcp_read = 1, wants_tcp_write = is_client;
  int call_ssl_read_instead_of_write = 0;
  int call_ssl_write_instead_of_read = 0;

  for (;;) {
    printf("selecting\n");
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
    if (wants_tcp_read) {
      FD_SET(sockfd, &read_fds);
    }

    if (wants_tcp_write) {
      FD_SET(sockfd, &write_fds);
    }

    struct timeval timeout = { 1, 0 };

    if (select(sockfd + 1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, &timeout)) {
      if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &read_fds)) {
        printf("readable\n");

        if (connecting) {
          ACTION action = ssl_connect(ssl, &wants_tcp_write, &connecting);
          if (action == CONTINUE) {
            continue;
          } else if (action == BREAK) {
            break;
          }
        } else {
          ACTION action;
          if (call_ssl_write_instead_of_read) {
            action = ssl_write(ssl, &wants_tcp_write, &call_ssl_write_instead_of_read, is_client, 0);
          } else {
            action = ssl_read(ssl, &wants_tcp_write, &call_ssl_read_instead_of_write);
          }

          if (action == CONTINUE) {
            continue;
          } else if (action == BREAK) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &write_fds)) {
        printf("writable\n");

        if (connecting) {
          wants_tcp_write = 0;

          ACTION action = ssl_connect(ssl, &wants_tcp_write, &connecting);
          if (action == CONTINUE) {
            continue;
          } else if (action == BREAK) {
            break;
          }
        } else {
          ACTION action;
          if (call_ssl_read_instead_of_write) {
            action = ssl_read(ssl, &wants_tcp_write, &call_ssl_read_instead_of_write);
          } else {
            action = ssl_write(ssl, &wants_tcp_write, &call_ssl_write_instead_of_read, is_client, 0);
          }

          if (action == CONTINUE) {
            continue;
          } else if (action == BREAK) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (is_client & !connecting && !call_ssl_write_instead_of_read) {
      ACTION action = ssl_write(ssl, &wants_tcp_write, &call_ssl_write_instead_of_read, is_client, 1);
      if (action == CONTINUE) {
        continue;
      } else if (action == BREAK) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  SSL_CTX_free(ssl_ctx);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I realized i forgot about ssl_pending

Comment: I also did not include the libray cleanup calls shown here: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization

Comment: Under which license is this code released? Thanks!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179128/how-to-manage-the-error-queue-in-openssl-ssl-get-error-and-err-get-error

Answer (score 3):

In terms of error handling, it seems to be much safer to call `ERR_clear_error()` before any call to `SSL_read()`, `SSL_write()`, `SSL_accept`, and so on. See [one of the few reported cases](https://www.arangodb.com/2014/07/started-hate-openssl/) where error management has messed up people.

Basically, each thread shares an error stack. While `SSL_get_error()` grab the latest error associated to a ssl session, it does not remove it. `ERR_get_error` does. You might be in a case where you are reading an error from a previous call. This API is really... dubious, for the least.

Comment: Another instance: http://www.educatedguesswork.org/2005/03/curse_you_opens.html theoretically if you clear the error stack carefully after each call, then you don't have to do the resets.  Or if you carefully read them after every failed calll.  But then there's stuff like SSL_Shutdown that expects you to sometimes ignore certain failures that are pushed onto the error stack? What? With no mention of what to do with them? ai ai...

Comment: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/8470 is another instance of the madness...if old messages are accidentally left on there (and there are comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179128/how-to-manage-the-error-queue-in-openssl-ssl-get-error-and-err-get-error saying it can push up to 5 messages sometimes, and if you clear, say, just one of them not all) then it'll pop off the old messages first next time you make a call and won't tell you, for instance, that it was a WANT_WRITE call or what not.  Whoa!  So yeah I guess the safest way is to just clear it every time...?

Answer (score 2):

This is kinda minor, but still sticks out to me:

> ```
> typedef enum {
>     CONTINUE,
>     BREAK,
>     NEITHER
> } ACTION;
> ```

Here, `ACTION` is the type name, so just the first letter should be capitalized.  This will also help with differentiating this type name from the actual `enum` values.

```
typedef enum {
    CONTINUE,
    BREAK,
    NEITHER
} Action;
```

Comment: Thanks for reading! Honestly I am mostly looking for feedback on the ssl calls since the library is quite tricky to use. Almost every example I can find does not work for a general purpose socket.

Answer (score 2):

Also kind of minor:

In the `ssl_connect` function, the last `return NEITHER;` is unreachable. In `ssl_read` and `ssl_write`, I suggest you implement it similarly: move `return NEITHER;` into the `else`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately it is not a bug.